# Serializing a static inner class with FlexJSON

Tags: java, class, serialization, inner-classes, flexjson

I'm trying to serialize this inner class

```
static class functionMessage{
    String type = "function";
    String id;
    String function;
    Object parameters;

    public functionMessage(String ID, String Function, Boolean Parameters) {
        this.id = ID;
        this.function = Function;
        this.parameters = (Boolean) Parameters;
    }
}
```

with

```
new flexjson.JSONSerializer().exclude("*.class").serialize( 
    new functionMessage(
        "container", 
        "showContainer", 
        Boolean.TRUE
    ) 
)
```

but only `{}` is retured.

If I try to add `public` before each member variable, it gives this error:

```
flexjson.JSONException: Error trying to deepSerialize  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class flexjson.BeanProperty can not access a member of class with modifiers "public"
```

I've tried to follow the [example](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/), but it doesn't show how `Person` is constructed, and I don't know how making the class a `static` inner class affects this as I'm still fairly new to Java.

I've also tried to read all of the solutions provided for that error given by Google but still nothing.

How can `flexjson.JSONSerializer()` return all of the member variables of a `static` inner class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but only {} is retured.

Apparently `flexjson` uses getters to resolve JSON elements. Your class doesn't have any.

Just add corresponding getters

```
public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getFunction() {
    return function;
}

public Object getParameters() {
    return parameters;
}
```

As for

> If I try to add public before each member variable, it gives this error:

That's because your `static` class has default package access and its fields are therefore not visible to any class outside of the package its declared in.

Comment: Genius!  Thank you so much!  Sorry for polluting the site with noob questions, but I'm still too new to Java to limp fully through these problems myself.  One day I'll have a good grasp on this awesome language!

Comment: @Gracchus It wasn't obvious. Some JSON parser/generators use the fields themselves to serialize an object. `flexjson` decided to use mutators/accessors (like `jackson`). You just have to know what to look for.